# set from array of objects still returning duplicates

Tags: javascript, wordpress, set

I have a callback function which hits a wordpress api multiple times and concatenates an array of posts of a specific category from the response. It works fine however when it gets to the last call it adds some duplicates to the array which i think is causing problems further down the line.

I've tried to remove these duplicates using a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) but for some reason these duplicates are still being returned.

below i'm logging the length of the array.

At the time of writing there are:

**40** unique posts of category *blog*

**257** unique posts of category *features*

however for the features the array still contains **300** items

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening ?

```
function getPostsOfType(category) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const getData = (category, number = 0, page = 0) =>
      fetch(`https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/www.accessaa.co.uk/posts?category=${category}&number=${number}&page=${page}&order_by=date`)
        .then(res => res.json())

    const found = (category) => getData(category).then(json => json.found);

    found(category)
      .then((value) => {
          return Math.ceil(value/100);
      })
      .then((callsToMake) => {
          let tasks = [];
          for (i = 0; i < callsToMake; i++) {
              tasks.push(getData(category, 100, i)) //<--- Fill tasks array with promises that will eventually return a value
          }
          return Promise.all(tasks); //<-- Run these tasks in parallel and return an array of the resolved values of the N Promises.
      })
      .then((arrOfPosts) => {
          let allPosts = [];
          for(var elem of arrOfPosts)
              allPosts = allPosts.concat(elem.posts);
          console.log(Array.from(new Set(allPosts)).length);
      }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
      })
  })
}

getPostsOfType('blog') //returns 40
getPostsOfType('features') //should return 257(ish) still returns 300
```

Comment: The object references will not be identical, even though the data inside may be - hence why you're getting duplicates in a Set. You'll need to map them yourself based on id or some other property that determines whether the object is unique or a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried solving the problem using [lodash.uniqby](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#uniqBy) like so `uniqBy(allPosts, 'ID')` however now i'm only getting 200 posts back.

Comment: Try `_.uniqWith(allPosts, _.isEqual);` That will do a deep comparison to determine if all values of the objects are equal. Are you sure you have more than 200 unique IDs? You can check that easily with `new Set(allPosts.map(post => post.ID)).size`

Comment: Also, if your posts for different categories are stored in different DB tables, they can very well have duplicate IDs. i.e. `{id: 1, category: 'blog'}, {id: 1, category: 'features'}`. If that is the case, you will have to do a uniq by id & category (or any other fields that guarantee uniqueness)